# Mapping an IntEnum to a second set of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have generated an `IntEnum` with different Datatypes

```
class DataTypes(IntEnum):
    Bytei = 0  # RAM buffer variable            8    bit    (on-off input)
    Byteo = 1  # RAM buffer variable            8    bit    (on-off output)
    Bytem = 2  # RAM buffer variable            8    bit    (flag)
    Wordi = 3  # RAM system variable           16    bit    (signed int)
    Wordo = 4  # RAM system variable           16    bit    (signed int)
    Wordm = 5  # RAM buffer variable           16    bit    (signed int)
    Wordp = 6  # E2PROM variable (parameter)   16    bit    (signed int)
    Dworm = 7  # RAM buffer variable           32    bit    (signed long int)
    Dworp = 8  # E2PROM variable (parameter)   32    bit    (signed long int)
```

The integers of the enums are specified for communication, so I would like to keep this enum as it is or least something similar that has the same associations.

As visible in the comments the datatypes have different sizes I would like to get the size of a datatype in someway. I could write a function to map the the parameters

```
def map_types(DataType):
    if not 0 <= DataType <=8 :
        size = 0
    elif DataType <3:
        size = 1
    elif DataType <7:
        size = 2
    else:
        size = 4

    return size
```

but is there a nice, cleaner and/or more pythonic way?

Comment: You could define `map_types` as a property inside the `DataTypes` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to have an extra `size` attribute on your `DataType` Enum (and maybe a `__doc__` as well).  You can roll your own (if using the stdlib or the `enum34` backport, or take advantage of `aenum`'s advanced features<sup>1</sup>.

Rolling your own with `enum34` (py2/3) or the `stdlib enum` (3.4+):

```
from enum import IntEnum

class DataTypes(IntEnum):

    def __new__(cls, value, size, doc):
        obj = int.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

    def __init__(self, value, size, doc):
        # value already handled, ignore it
        self.size = size
        self.__doc__ = doc

    Bytei = 0, 8,  'RAM buffer variable         (on-off input)'
    Byteo = 1, 8,  'RAM buffer variable         (on-off output)'
    Bytem = 2, 8,  'RAM buffer variable         (flag)'
    Wordi = 3, 16, 'RAM system variable         (signed int)'
    Wordo = 4, 16, 'RAM system variable         (signed int)'
    Wordm = 5, 16, 'RAM buffer variable         (signed int)'
    Wordp = 6, 16, 'E2PROM variable (parameter) (signed int)'
    Dworm = 7, 32, 'RAM buffer variable         (signed long int)'
    Dworp = 8, 32, 'E2PROM variable (parameter) (signed long int)'
```

Taking advantage of `aenum`'s features (py2/3):

```
from aenum import IntEnum

class DataTypes(IntEnum):

    _init_ = 'value size __doc__'

    Bytei = 0, 8,  'RAM buffer variable         (on-off input)'
    Byteo = 1, 8,  'RAM buffer variable         (on-off output)'
    Bytem = 2, 8,  'RAM buffer variable         (flag)'
    Wordi = 3, 16, 'RAM system variable         (signed int)'
    Wordo = 4, 16, 'RAM system variable         (signed int)'
    Wordm = 5, 16, 'RAM buffer variable         (signed int)'
    Wordp = 6, 16, 'E2PROM variable (parameter) (signed int)'
    Dworm = 7, 32, 'RAM buffer variable         (signed long int)'
    Dworp = 8, 32, 'E2PROM variable (parameter) (signed long int)'
```

And in use:

```
--> print repr(DataTypes.Bytei)
<DataTypes.Bytei: 0>

--> print DataTypes.Bytei
DataTypes.Bytei

--> print DataTypes.Bytei.size
8

--> print DataTypes.Bytei.__doc__
RAM buffer variable         (on-off input)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: The `aenum` looks really nice and clean. So is `value` the keyword for integer evaluation or how does this declaration know that `DataTypes.Bytei == 0` is `true`?

Comment: `value` is whatever will end up being the `.value` attribute.  `Bytei` is comparable with `int` because `DataTypes` is based on `IntEnum`.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner way would be to move the function into the class.

```
class DataTypes(IntEnum):
    Bytei = 0  # RAM buffer variable            8    bit    (on-off input)
    Byteo = 1  # RAM buffer variable            8    bit    (on-off output)
    Bytem = 2  # RAM buffer variable            8    bit    (flag)
    Wordi = 3  # RAM system variable           16    bit    (signed int)
    Wordo = 4  # RAM system variable           16    bit    (signed int)
    Wordm = 5  # RAM buffer variable           16    bit    (signed int)
    Wordp = 6  # E2PROM variable (parameter)   16    bit    (signed int)
    Dworm = 7  # RAM buffer variable           32    bit    (signed long int)
    Dworp = 8  # E2PROM variable (parameter)   32    bit    (signed long int)

    @property 
    def size(self):  # You could also link it to the name.  If self.name.startswith('Byte') ...
        if self.value < 3:
            return 1
        elif self.value < 7:
            return 2
        else:
            return 4

    def __repr__(self):
        old_repr = super(DataTypes, self).__repr__()
        return old_repr.replace('>', ', size: {}>'.format(self.size))

for thing in DataTypes:
    print(repr(thing), thing.value, thing.size, 2 < thing, thing < 2, sep=' | ')
```

outputs:

```
<DataTypes.Bytei: 0, size: 1> | 0 | 1 | False | True
<DataTypes.Byteo: 1, size: 1> | 1 | 1 | False | True
<DataTypes.Bytem: 2, size: 1> | 2 | 1 | False | False
<DataTypes.Wordi: 3, size: 2> | 3 | 2 | True | False
<DataTypes.Wordo: 4, size: 2> | 4 | 2 | True | False
<DataTypes.Wordm: 5, size: 2> | 5 | 2 | True | False
<DataTypes.Wordp: 6, size: 2> | 6 | 2 | True | False
<DataTypes.Dworm: 7, size: 4> | 7 | 4 | True | False
<DataTypes.Dworp: 8, size: 4> | 8 | 4 | True | False
```

#### answers to specific questions from comment below

the `@property` decorator makes a method look and act like an attribute. without the decorator, in order to get the size you would call `DataTypes.Bytei.size()`. With the decorator `DataTypes.Bytie.size` returns the same thing. So `@property` is unnecessary here, but I thought that since the that acted like a property of the object and not a method, it would be nice to make it work like on.

`super` calls the method of the parent class.  so, `super(DataTypes, self).__repr__()` means get the `repr` using `self` and use the `repr` function from the parent class (this returns a string).  then, since it's a `str`, that is, indeed, `str.replace`.

Comment: For me as a python(and kinda OOP) newbie your solution is hard to understand with all those keywords. I get the general concept but what are `@property` and `super()` doing? is `replace` derived from `string.replace`?  If you could add this to the answer, it would greatly improve it.